# windows 10 third party credential providers produces multiple password tiles

Tags: windows-10, lockscreen, credential-providers

i have been testing with third party credential providers, till windows 8.1 i was getting the third party credential provider working fine. once i upgraded to windows 10 i am getting multiple tiles with the name of Password. each password tile is mapped to individual user who logged in the machine.

i know that windows 10 credential provider settings has been changed

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt158211(v=vs.85).aspx

as mentioned in the KB there is fallback crentail provider will be available for every user.

is that the reason for multiple tile getting produced.
i have attached image the "Password" tiles are coming once i install third password credential provider
[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4LTN.jpg)